# "any of the" or "other"?

Tags: word-choice

In the following passage, is it advisable to replace "any of the" with "other"? Is it okay to leave it as it is?

> Large population-based studies show that both short sleep and long sleep are associated with an increased risk of heart attacks and strokes, as well as the long-term progression of things like atherosclerosis, diabetes, coronary artery disease and **any of the** major cardiovascular diseases.

My question is why "other" should be used instead of "any of the." And I think it has to do with the preceding "coronary artery disease."

Comment: "and of the" means something completely different to "other". What makes you think they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is more natural to use "other", and not without reason.

By using "**any of the**", you are implying "**all**", so you are saying **definitively** that "both short sleep and long sleep are associated with an increased risk of ... **all** the major cardiovascular diseases."

Unless you are absolutely certain that short/long sleep is, in fact, associated with **every** major cardiovascular disease, **"other" is the only correct answer** here.  "Other major cardiovascular diseases" can be two "other" diseases... or all of the others... you simply don't know for sure the number and therefore should not (cannot) say with certainty that it is associated with all for fear of misleading your audience.

Comment: My question is why "other" should be used instead of "any of the."  And I think it has to do with the preceding "coronary artery disease." Do you want to revise your answer?

Comment: Let's assume that the author really means short sleep is associated with every major cardiovascular disease.

Comment: You seem to be implying that "coronary artery disease" is not a cardiovascular disease.  If that were true, then "any of the" would be better, since not all of the previous examples used were cardiovascular diseases.  But since coronary artery disease is cardiovascular, "other" is still a better choice.

Comment: Thank you. Could you incorporate this fact of coronary artery disease being a cardiovascular disease, and how this determines our choice of "other" over "any," into your answer?

Comment: If the author really does mean that short sleep is associated with EVERY major cardiovascular disease then, sure, "any of the" might work in a pinch, but would sound strange to a native ear.  Using "any of the" implies that no cardiovascular diseases have been mentioned in the list previously (e.g. thing A, thing B, AND all of things that include A; it's redundant), so that would not work.

Comment: @Apollyon - Clarifications like the one you made in your first comment here belong **in your question**, not in a comment beneath an answer. Other people reading your question need to find these details in the question itself, not interspersed beneath various answers.